# Averaging periodic signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, folding

I have a signal that repeats periodically as the one attached in the figure (the same pattern repeats 4 times). I would like to create a template of this signal as the averaging of the 4 repetitions. Which is the best approach for my problem? I know the answer might be obvious to experts in signal processing, I have tried searching for signal folding techniques but couldn't find anything useful. I am prototyping it in Matlab.

[image]

Comment: Cross correlate with itself, find the peaks and align chunks of a given length.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your signal length is dividable by 4 and each of the repetitions is 1/4th of this, simply use:

```
mean(reshape(signal,[],4),2)
```

`reshape` puts each repetition into one column, then the mean over all columns is calculated.